# Como fixar o eixo X e impedir a rotação do objeto altere o eixo?

Tags: unity-5

Toda vez que eu movo o objeto ele tende a rotacionar, devido ao movimento natural dele, porém, quando ele rotaciona ele altera o eixo x, fazendo com que a movimentação dele fique confusa por ter perdido a referência do eixo.Como faço para que a rotação não influencie no eixo x?

```
    public class teste : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float forca = 300f;
    public Rigidbody2D Bola;
    public float movdir = 5f;
    public float moveesq = -5f;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Bola.AddForce(new Vector2(0, forca * Time.deltaTime), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            Bola.transform.Translate(new Vector2(movdir * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            Bola.transform.Translate(new Vector2(moveesq * Time.deltaTime, 0));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Você está falando de rotação, mas em momento algum usas-te a transform de rotação, `Bola.transform.Rotate();`

Comment: Sim, porque in game quando o objeto está em movimento ele rotaciona por conta da própria física. Eu não tenho problema com a rotação em si, mas o fato dela alterar o meu eixo x

Comment: Na mecânica clássica, quando você rotaciona algo numa direção ele tende a rotacionar na direção oposta, o que pode gerar uma alteração no eixo x, devido a lei de newton sobre ação e reação, recomendo olhar as opções do objeto no unity que tratam da física, como cinematic, dynamic, static e etc.